# chatter posts in sites pages?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Can chatter posts be accessed in sites pages?  Both, reading chatter posts and adding comments from a sites page that is using the guest site user login account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an Apex controller that is [without sharing](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm), then yes, you can expose Chatter posts on a Sites page (although you might have to recreate the user experience, I'm not sure if the default Visualforce components would work that way).

Adding comments is another matter though -- I doubt you'd succeed in getting the guest user to add a comment (although this is pure conjecture -- I haven't actually tried it myself so who knows, it might work).  In this case you'd probably have to write the controller such that it added any comments as some existing regular user in the system.

Also, it's worth noting the existence of [Chatter Answers](http://na3.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/questions_portal_overview.htm), which is a way to expose a limited chatter feed on Sites.  If this maps to what you're trying to do then it might save you some time.